# Stripe functions hanging with no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe in NodeJS and am running into some problems with getting some basic functions to return values. For example, I am trying to create a customer with `stripe.customers.create()`. I put a console log before and after to see when it's done, the first console log fires but not the second:

```
export const createCustomer = async (agency) => {
    console.log('creating customer')
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
    console.log('done creating customer', customer)
    return customer;
}
```

I am getting no errors returned from the function, nothing printed to the console or anything. Is there a hang somewhere which I am not aware of do you think? I can't for the life of me figure out whats happening. To clarify: I'm using the latest version of the stripe package.

**Update**
If I try another stripe fucntion just above the customer create, it also doesn't work. for example I have put:

```
const ev = await stripe.events.retrieve('evt_1GYpLgA4Bo9i6RlnEavkEvWR');
console.log(ev);
```

Above the previous code and that isn't even returning anything either. I feel like I must be missing a pretty vital step somewhere...

**Update 18/04**
Hi everyone so I have deployed my code to run in a firebase cloud function instead of in the app itself and the code runs without a hiccup now. My theory here is that potentially im trying to run the Stripe functions in an unsupported environment? Am I correct in thinking running an app with npm start for a ReactJS app gives to access to run NodeJS code? This is the only thing I can think of what may be causing this to happen.

Comment: From the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) it seems like `stripe.customers.create()` takes callback argument. Have you tried doing it like so?

Comment: Yeah i've tried this: `await stripe.customers.create({}, (err, customer) => {console.log(err) });` as that should at least return me an error if there is anything wrong but I get something from that either.

Comment: If you use a callback you don't need the `await` keyword

Comment: Ah yes you're correct. I've instead now moved a console log inside of the callback function to print either an error or customer but they both still never are printed , it's as if the callback function is never being reached

Comment: Does it work when you try to create the customer [using cURL](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=curl)?

Comment: Hi no I dont have any knowledge with using cURL. If it helps some of the other functions, such as creating a source with stripe, do appear to be working when I look at the developer console in the stripe dashboard.

Comment: Can you wrap the `await stripe.customers.create()` into a try and catch `try {...} catch(e) {console.log(e); }` and probably you will nee to pass in at least an empty object like `stripe.customers.create({})`

Comment: Hello @lewisnewson did you ever figure out the solution to this? I am trying to test this locally (on localhost:3000) but I keep getting an error even if I deploy stripe on firebase functions.

Comment: Hi @Mega_Noob, for me deploying the code to firebase functions worked because the library I was using wasn't geared up to me be used outside of that NodeJS environment so i'd maybe try deploying it there at debugging at that level